# Windows Server 2012 - Set-ADUser TsProfilePath not found / How to set?

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, windows-server-2012

I would set the TsProfilePath and the TsHomeDrive.

How can i do that with PowerShell?

In the attribute editor of active directory is no attribute for that.

With Google i found out that i have to use Set-QAdUser.... But Command not found!

Thanks in advance for ideas!

```
Get-ADUser MyTestUser | Set-ADUser -TsProfilePath "\\srv\profiles$\<username>"
```

Thats my example but its not working :(

I tried also `Get-QADUser` and `Set-QADUser` but the commands are unknown.

I mean the remote desktop attributes! Not the normal ProfilePath. Thats to easy :D

[image]

Comment: The QAD- commands are from a third party company called Quest who made a set of AD Administrative PowerShell cmdlets.

Comment: can you clarify that you need the Terminal Services ProfilePath and HomeDrive attributes or the regular ones?

Comment: I updated my question with a image. I need the remote desktop services profile. And there the profile path and the drive with path. This three options i would set with/per/via powershell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The QAD cmdlets can be found on [Quest's website](http://www.quest.com/powershell/activeroles-server.aspx)

If you need a pure generic PowerShell answer, I found the following article that explains the process but it doesn't seem too easy: [How Can I Edit Terminal Server Profiles for Users in Active Directory?](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2008/10/23/how-can-i-edit-terminal-server-profiles-for-users-in-active-directory.aspx)

EDIT:  Okay, I got curious so I gave it a try myself and it wasn't that hard actually:

```
Get-ADUser MyTestUser | ForEach-Object {
   $User = [ADSI]"LDAP://$($_.DistinguishedName)"
   $User.psbase.invokeset("TerminalServicesProfilePath","\\Server\Share\HomeDir\Profile")
   $User.psbase.invokeset("TerminalServicesHomeDrive","H:")
   $User.psbase.invokeset("TerminalServicesHomeDirectory","\\Server\Share\HomeDir") 
   $User.setinfo
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick edit. The last statement $User.setinfo should be $User.setinfo(). Otherwise, you get the OverloadDefinitions statement.